# Proving that $a,b$ are even integers

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I'm trying to prove the following theorem:

> Let $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$ . Then  $$a^{2}+b^{2}\equiv0\pmod 4 \iff a \;\text{and}\; b\;\text{are even}$$

I always struggle to prove some number is odd or even. How to prove it?
I thought of using the $(a+b)^2=a^2+2ab+b^2$ formula but not sure how.

Comment: There're only four cases to enumerate.

Answer (score 2):

If $c$ is even, then $c^2\equiv0 \pmod 4;$ if $c$ is odd, then $c^2\equiv1\pmod4$.

Therefore if $a$ and $b$ are both even,

> then $a^2+b^2\equiv0\pmod4;$

if $a$ and $b$ are both odd,

> then $a^2+b^2\equiv2\pmod4;$

and if one of $a$ and $b$ is even and the other is odd,

> then $a^2+b^2\equiv1\pmod4.$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: If $a$ or $b$ or both are odd, then $(2c+1)^2 = 4c^2+4c+1 \equiv 1 \mod 4$
and $(2c+1)^2 + (2d+1)^2= 4c^2+4c+4d^2+4d +2 \equiv 2 \mod 4$.

But if $a$ and $b$ are even, then $(2c)^2+(2d)^2 = 4c^2+4d^2\equiv 0\mod 4$.

Comment: what is $c$? why did you look at $(2c+1)^2$? Also what if only one of the numbers is odd?

Comment: @vesii: If $a$ is odd,then it can be written as $$a=2c+1$$ for some $c \in \Bbb Z$

Comment: @Wuestenflux You say "if a or b or both are odd..." but only consider the case when they are both odd.

Answer (score 0):

If both $a$ and $b$ are odd numbers then $a = 2k_1+1, b=2 k_2+1$ and you have that
$$
a^2+b^2 = (2k_1+1)^2+(2 k_2+1)^2 = 4k_1^2+4 k_2^2 +4k_1+4k_2+2 \equiv 2 (mod\,\, 4)
$$

If one is odd (for instance $a$) and the other is even, then $a =2 k_1+1, b=2k_2$ and

$$
a^2+b^2 = (2k_1+1)^2+(2k_2)^2 = 4k_1^2+4k_2^2+4k_1+1\equiv 1 (mod\,\,4)
$$

If both $a$ and $b$ are even, $a=2k_ 1, b=2k_2$ and
$$
a^2+b^2 = (2k_1)^2+(2k_2)^2=4k_1^2+ 4k_2^2 \equiv 0(mod\,\,4)
$$

So you see that $a^2+b^2$ can only be congruent with 0,1 or 2 (mod 4) and is congruent with 0 if and only if both $a$ and $b$ are even numbers.

Answer (score 0):

$\Rightarrow$:

By the rules of modular arithmetic we have
\begin{align}
0 
&= (a^2 + b^2) \bmod 4 \\
&= \left( \left( a^2 \bmod 4 \right) + \left( b^2 \bmod 4 \right)  \right) \bmod 4
\end{align}
For each summand we have
\begin{align}
x^2 \bmod 4
&= \left( \left( x \bmod 4 \right)  \left( x \bmod 4 \right)  \right) \bmod 4 \\
&\in 
\{ y^2 \bmod 4 \mid y \in \{0,1,2,3\} \} 
= \{ 0, 1 \} \quad (*)
\end{align}
So for the expression
$$
\left( \left( a^2 \bmod 4 \right) + \left( b^2 \bmod 4 \right)  \right) \bmod 4
$$
we have the possible cases $0+0$, $0+1$, $1+0$ and $1+1$. This vanishes modulo $4$ only for the case $0+0$.

Now $x^2 \bmod 4$ only vanishes for $x \bmod 4 \in \{ 0, 2 \}$, see display $(*)$, which means
$x = 4k$ or $x = 4k + 2$ for some integer $k$ and both cases can be divided by $2$, thus are even.

$\Leftarrow$:

$a = 2p$ and $b=2q$ for some integers $p, q$. Then we have
\begin{align}
(a^2 + b^2) \bmod 4 
&= (4p^2 + 4q^2) \bmod 4 \\
&= \left( \left(4p^2 \bmod 4\right) + \left(4q^2 \bmod 4 \right)\right) \bmod 4 \\ 
&= (0 + 0) \bmod 4 \\
&= 0
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

$$a^{2}+b^{2}\equiv0\pmod 4 \iff(a+b)^2-2ab\equiv 0\pmod{4}.$$
If both $a$ and $b$ are odd, then:
$$\begin{align}a+b\equiv 0\pmod{2} &\Rightarrow (a+b)^2\equiv 0\pmod{4}, \text{but}\\
2ab\equiv 0 \pmod{2} &\Rightarrow \qquad 2ab\not\equiv 0\pmod{4}\end{align}$$
If $a$ is odd and $b$ is even, then:
$$\begin{align}2ab&\equiv 0 \pmod{4}, \text{but}\\
a+b\not\equiv 0\pmod{2} \Rightarrow (a+b)^2&\not\equiv 0\pmod{4}\end{align}$$
Finally, if $a$ and $b$ are even, then:
$$\begin{align}a+b\equiv 0\pmod{2} \Rightarrow (a+b)^2&\equiv 0\pmod 4\\
2ab&\equiv 0\pmod 4\end{align}$$